# UITableViewCell subclass not showing correct size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, subclass

I have a nib file for a UITableViewCell subclass I made, it's height is set to 25 in the nib, however when the application loads, this is not the case. It loads to the default size. Here is my code for the implementation of the cell.

```
    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = choreCell;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I've tried setting the frame with `cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 25)` however it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell height is specified in the `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method of your table view's delegate.